# Error XalanXPathException when using hours-from-duration xpath function in ibm db2 xslt transformation

Tags: xpath, db2, xslt-2.0

**Input XML:**
`<test><TotalDuration>PT1H32M7S</TotalDuration></test>`
**Input XSLT:**

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:template match="/test">
    Hours=<xsl:value-of select="fn:hours-from-duration(TotalDuration)"/> hr
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

**Expected Output:** Hours=1 hr

**Instead Getting:** [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL16280N The XSLT processor returned the following error: "XalanXPathException: The function number 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath". SQLSTATE=225X0

Comment: I see a `XalanXpathException`. It might mean that you are in fact using Xalan XSLT processor wich is an XSLT 1.0 processor and not an XSLT 2.0 one.

Answer (score 0):

> Expected Output: Hours=1 hr
>
> Instead Getting: [IBM][DB2/NT64]
>   SQL16280N The XSLT processor returned
>   the following error:
>   "XalanXPathException: The function
>   number 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath".
>   SQLSTATE=225X0

**This is so clear**: The XSLT processor you are using (Xalan) doesn't implement XSLT 2.0.

You need to feed XSLT 2.0 code only to a XSLT processor that implements XSLT 2.0.

Comment: The transformation takes place in DB2 database, ie the XSLT processor is inside db2. Not sure which xslt processors are support by DB2 database.

Comment: @pdshah: It is a well-known fact that there is no Xalan XSLT 2.0 processor at present. And the error message identifies the processor as "Xalan". So, is there anything that is not clear? You cannot give an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet to an XSLT 1.0 processor. Fullstop.

Comment: @Alejandro I appreciate your quick responses. It makes sense, Xlang implements xslt 1 and hence throws exception. Just wondering if I can configure DB2 to use another engine like Saxon. It seems IBM has it own XSLT 2.0 engine too [ref](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/12/was7xmlfp).